# Observable Subscription Not Firing

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I am starting to take a look at Reactive Extensions and how they can be applied to common scenarios to enable more manageable and readable code.

I am playing with basic concepts right now, and have built a simple class:

```
public class ValidatableObject<TValue>
{
    public bool IsValid { get; private set; } = true;
    public TValue Value { get; }
    public ICollection<IValidationRule<TValue>> Rules { get; }

    public ValidatableObject(TValue value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Rules = new List<IValidationRule<TValue>>();
        Rules.ToObservable()
             .All(rule => rule.Check(Value))
             .Subscribe(b => IsValid = b);
    }
}

public interface IValidationRule<T>
{
    bool Check(T value);
}

public class FailingValidationRule<T> : IValidationRule<T>
{
    public bool Check(T value) => false;
}

public static void main()
{
    var theObject = new object();
    var v = new ValidatableObject<object>(theObject);

    // v.IsValid should be true

    v.Rules.Add(new FailingValidationRule<object>());

    // v.IsValid should be false
}
```

Simple unit tests on this class show that it's not acting as I'm expecting, and I'm probably missing a fundamental piece. What I expect is that when I add an item to Rules, each rule in Rules will be evaluated, and the result will be stored in IsValid. However, I am not seeing IsValid being updated to false after adding a rule designed to fail to the Rules collection.

This also ignores the fact that the result of the evaluation on the Check method may change, based on changes to properties of Value. I can see that the Check method may need to return an observable here as well.

Why is IsValid not updating in this case, and what does the minimal implementation look like to set up this sort of behavior?

Comment: It would be super if you provided a [mcve] as I can't run your code to see it in action.

Comment: But just as a quick answer for now - your `Rules` collection, in the code you've provided, is empty, so it cannot produce a value.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're saying in your question. The `.ToObservable()` operator is a once-off snap shot of the collection at that point in time. Any future additions to the collection do not go through the observable.

Comment: I see, I was under the impression that ToObservable() would watch for change as well. What is the better set up in this case? Should Rules be a Subject instead, which would allow me to both add items and observe for change? I've been reading a lot and think I saw to avoid creating Subject's and instead rely on the extensions.

Comment: Yes, you're right to avoid using a `Subject` in general, but there are places where it is perfectly fine. The place to use them is when you want to create an adhoc observable sequence. I'm putting an answer together now.

Comment: Instead of a List<T>, you can use a BindingList<T>, and subscribe to the ListChanged event. Also if you subscribe, you need to dispose of that subscription at some point - implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.ToObservable()` operator is a once-off snap shot of the collection at that point in time. Any future additions to the collection do not go through the observable.

So you need to use something that allows you to observe the changes.

To give you the most immediate parallel to what you're currently using I'd suggest changing from `ICollection<IValidationRule<TValue>>` to `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<IValidationRule<TValue>>`. Please note that this is not the way you should do it, but I wanted to give you something that you can immediately see relates to your code in your question.

You can then write your code like this:

```
public class ValidatableObject<TValue>
{
    public bool IsValid { get; private set; } = true;
    public TValue Value { get; }
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<IValidationRule<TValue>> Rules { get; }

    public ValidatableObject(TValue value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Rules = new ObservableCollection<IValidationRule<TValue>>();

        Observable
            .FromEventPattern<
                    System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler,
                    System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
                h => Rules.CollectionChanged += h,
                h => Rules.CollectionChanged -= h)
            .Select(ep => Rules.All(rule => rule.Check(Value)))
            .Subscribe(b => IsValid = b);
    }
}
```

Notice that I've used `FromEventPattern` to build an observable from the `CollectionChanged` event, but I'm still using LINQ to Objects to evaluate the rules. The way you had done this in your code you could only ever set `IsValid` to `true`. The way I've done it will let it set to `true` or `false` depending on the rules.

I created a couple of test rules:

```
public class ValidationRuleTrue<T> : IValidationRule<T>
{
    public bool Check(T value) => true;
}

public class ValidationRuleFalse<T> : IValidationRule<T>
{
    public bool Check(T value) => false;
}
```

Then I ran this:

```
void Main()
{
    var theObject = new object();
    var v = new ValidatableObject<object>(theObject);
    Console.WriteLine(v.IsValid);
    v.Rules.Add(new ValidationRuleTrue<object>());
    Console.WriteLine(v.IsValid);
    v.Rules.Add(new ValidationRuleFalse<object>());
    Console.WriteLine(v.IsValid);
}
```

I got:

```
True
True
False
```

which is to be expected.

**However, your code is not well structured for using Rx**. It is possible that your query could easy be structured to push the observable pipeline to a different thread. If that happens the code won't produce the right results.

To give you a example, try this simple change:

```
        Observable
            .FromEventPattern<
                    System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler,
                    System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
                h => Rules.CollectionChanged += h,
                h => Rules.CollectionChanged -= h)
            .Select(ep => Rules.All(rule => rule.Check(Value)))
            .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
            .Subscribe(b => IsValid = b);
```

Now when I run the same test code I get this:

```
True
True
True
```

Basically the final `Console.WriteLine(v.IsValid);` is run before the observable running on the `Scheduler.Default` updates `IsValid`. You have a race condition.

If you're going to start using Rx more you've easily create a query that uses schedulers that run on different threads. So you need to write your class in a way that makes sense for Rx.

Try it like this:

```
public class ValidatableObject<TValue>
{
    public IObservable<bool> IsValid { get; private set; }
    public TValue Value { get; }

    public IEnumerable<IValidationRule<TValue>> Rules { get; }
    private ObservableCollection<IValidationRule<TValue>> _rules;

    public IDisposable AddRule(IValidationRule<TValue> rule)
    {
        _rules.Add(rule);
        return Disposable.Create(() => _rules.Remove(rule));
    }

    public ValidatableObject(TValue value)
    {
        Value = value;

        _rules = new ObservableCollection<IValidationRule<TValue>>();

        this.IsValid =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<
                        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler,
                        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
                    h => _rules.CollectionChanged += h,
                    h => _rules.CollectionChanged -= h)
                .Select(ep => _rules.All(rule => rule.Check(Value)))
                .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default);
    }
}
```

Take note of two things.

(1) `IsValid` is now an `IObservable<bool>` which gets rid of the race condition.

(2) that the rules are not exposed as an `ObservableCollection` for the entire outside world to manipulate, but instead there's a separate `AddRule` method to add a rule and an `IDisposable` to remove the rule. This means that only the code that added the rule is able to remove it. It's got far better control. It's not 100% needed for your code to work - you certainly could expose the `ObservableCollection` - but it's a good way to think of operations in an Rx world.

Now I can write my test code like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var theObject = new object();
    var v = new ValidatableObject<object>(theObject);

    var subscription = v.IsValid.Subscribe(isValid => Console.WriteLine(isValid));

    var rule1 = v.AddRule(new ValidationRuleTrue<object>());
    var rule2 = v.AddRule(new ValidationRuleFalse<object>());
    rule2.Dispose(); //remove `rule2`
}
```

I get out the expected values of:

```
True
False
True
```

---

Here's the basic way I'd look at implementing the observing of the value itself:

```
public interface IValidationRule<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool Check(T value);
}

public class ValidatableObject<TValue> where TValue : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IObservable<bool> IsValid { get; private set; }
    public TValue Value { get; }

    public IEnumerable<IValidationRule<TValue>> Rules { get; }
    private ObservableCollection<IValidationRule<TValue>> _rules;

    public IDisposable AddRule(IValidationRule<TValue> rule)
    {
        _rules.Add(rule);
        return Disposable.Create(() => _rules.Remove(rule));
    }

    public ValidatableObject(TValue value)
    {
        Value = value;

        _rules = new ObservableCollection<IValidationRule<TValue>>();

        var rulesChanged = 
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<
                        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler,
                        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
                    h => _rules.CollectionChanged += h,
                    h => _rules.CollectionChanged -= h)
                .Select(ep => Unit.Default);

        var valueChanged =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<
                        PropertyChangedEventHandler,
                        PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                    h => value.PropertyChanged += h,
                    h => value.PropertyChanged -= h)
                .Select(ep => Unit.Default);

        this.IsValid =
            Observable
                .Merge(rulesChanged, valueChanged)
                .Select(ep => _rules.All(rule => rule.Check(Value)))
                .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default);
    }
}
```

Comment: I love this community. Fantastic answer, thank you. Lots to digest there for me. I made an edit to my question, basically I haven't even considered the fact yet that the Check method may return different results based on the state of Value. Don't give it away, but am I on the right track in thinking that Check should return an IObservable<bool> if I'm going down the rabbit hole?

Comment: @MaxHampton - `Check` probably doesn't need to return `IObservable<bool>`. If you're observing the changes to the value then you just have a second trigger for your `IsValid` observable.

Comment: @MaxHampton - I've added the code to the end of my answer for observing the object itself.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense. Thanks again, helps a lot as I'm getting my feet wet.